# POST request to WebApi using Curl - character encoding issue

Tags: curl, unicode, character-encoding, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

We have a WebApi service which accepts POST requests. The information in the POST request has this unicode character - ¡ (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a1/index.htm)

When we test the service using Fiddler, the information is received correctly on the server. But while doing a POST of same information using curl, the character gets changed to this one from Specials block - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

Any idea on why this is happening and how we can get Curl request to POST correctly encoded stuff would be appreciated

Edit: 
curl request

```
curl --trace-ascii debug.txt -d "=VALT ¡ OFFER = '111501383'" http://localhost:25980/api/uni
```

Api controller code

```
// POST api/<controller>
public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
// code to process the value
}
```

Fiddler request (using composer tab)

```
POST http://localhost:25980/api/uni HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-IN,en;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=US-ASCII
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 47
Host: localhost:25980

"=VALT ¡ OFFER = '111501383'"
```

Comment: Can you add your curl code that sends request please. Also, `ApiContoller` code would be helpful.

Comment: updated question with code

Comment: This is curl on Windows right? Non-ASCII characters on the command line can be tricky. Is this a unicode (/U) console?

Answer (score 4):

This is a suggestion. I'll try to replicate your problem later today and will update the answer.

> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=US-ASCII

This line specifies that your data is encoded using `US-ACSII` encoding scheme, which does not include `¡` character. Try to set it to `UTF-8` using this option:

```
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, but it looks the character they're *trying* to send is actually ASCII 0xa1, which may be confusing curl. I'm guessing they're actually sending UTF-8 0xc2a1 though.